# How do I prevent the Google API from being used by others?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I'm going to make a project using the Google translate api and I'm thinking of uploading this project to a server and just sharing it with my friends. But unfortunately the Api Key that I will use in the project can be accessed clearly in the JavaScript file. This is a very bad situation. To prevent this, I have limited the Google Cloud Api and as far as I understand it is only allowed to be used on the links I allow. It cannot be used on other links. Now my main question is, is this method enough to protect Api from malicious people? Do I need to do anything else? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I wouldn't provide the API key in the frontend. I would send the requests from the frontend to my own backend, add the API key there and send the requests to Google.

Comment: So what's the best and easiest way to do this? Can you give some information?

Comment: [Google's quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) for NodeJS is useful.

Comment: Develop and host a backend that works as a proxy and adds the API key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a server for that which will perform OAuth and then send an API request to google.

You can get help about how to implement OAuth from this topic provided by google: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

If you send/attach your API key in frontend like javascript which is basically a frontend language then it can be used to:

- Send fake requests which will use all of the bandwidth etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consult the TOS.

On November 5th 2014 [Google made some changes to the APIs terms of Service](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.dk/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html).

Like you I had an issue with the following line.

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private
> keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

That is however really only an issue if you are releasing the source code of your app as an Open source project for example.

If your just hosting this on a server then what you shoudl do is set up limitations for the api key [adding_application_restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en&visit_id=637804398763838529-3800121338&rd=1#adding_application_restrictions)  you can limit it so that the api key can only be used from your server and no where else.

Answer (score -1):

Best practice in these cases is to use [`.env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) files to keep data like API keys private.